# Django model object exists() return "" instead of "None"

Tags: django, django-models, exists

So for a basic delivery form, i have a dropdown called "customer" in which customer is specified in first name, last name and prefix.

For now the dropdown shows:

Customer:

- Yvonne, Groot, de
- Kaleigh, Water, van der
- Tim, Klein, **None**
- Cees, Swart, **None**

What I'd like to do, is check is Customer.prefix exists and display a "" instead of the value "None".

```
#models.py
class Customer(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing the customer
    """
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__ (self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object.
        """
        if Customer.objects.filter(prefix='').exists(): 
        # Display first name, last name and prefix
            return '%s, %s, %s' % (self.last_name, self.first_name, self.prefix)    
        else:
        # Display first name and lastname
            return '%s, %s' % (self.last_name, self.first_name)
```

This instead will return an error: name 'prefix' is not defined, what would be the proper way for checking if the 'prefix' value exists?

Comment: Note that it isn't usually recommended to use `null=True` for CharFields. It means that you have two empty values, `''` and `None`. This can lead to bugs. In your question, for example, you check for `''`, but not `None`.

Answer (score 4):

Try to change method to this:

```
def __str__ (self):
    """
    String for representing the Model object.
    """
    if self.prefix: 
    # Display first name, last name and prefix
        return '%s, %s, %s' % (self.last_name, self.first_name, self.prefix)    
    else:
    # Display first name and lastname
        return '%s, %s' % (self.last_name, self.first_name)
```

In your version of code you never reach else statement since there are some records in DB with empty prefix and `if Customer.objects.filter(prefix='').exists()` is always true.

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply! So what it actually does is check if object is empty or not?

Comment: @KevinD. You are welcome! `Customer.objects.filter(prefix='').exists()` this is check if there are any objects in DB with empty prefix. I believe you have some. So it is always true. `self.prefix` on the other side check if current object prefix empty or not.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: @KevinD. Glad to help)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Customer.objects.filter(prefix__isnull=True).exists()` instead of `Customer.objects.filter(prefix='').exists()`.

or

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing the customer
    """
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__ (self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object.
        """
        data = [self.last_name, self.first_name, self.prefix]
        return ', '.join([field for field in data if field])
```

This way, it will return only those fields that are not None. So even if firstname or lastname is missing, you would still get a valid `__str__`.

Hope that helps.